# extending problem in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, overrides, magento-2.0

I'm extending **catalog product edit** page for this I have extended the `Edit.php` file from `vendor/magento-catalog/block/adminhtml/product`. My Changes is applying, but when i save the product it's not saving.

Same functionality working in first released **Magento 2 ver 1.0.0 beta**, but it's not working in recently released both **MEE and MCE** (ver 2.0.0 and 2.0.2).

For this I have written code as below.

**Learning/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Learning/Custom/Block/Adminhtml/Product/ProductEdit.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Product;

use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit;

class ProductEdit extends Edit
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'catalog/product/edit.phtml';


}
```

**Learning/Custom/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" type="Learning\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Product\ProductEdit"/>

</config>
```

**Learning/Custom/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit.phtml**

```
<h1> Hi I'm extending product edit page</h1>
....
//below is the product edit.phtml file coding here i'm not posting.
```

I have cleared the cache and I have ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. But still no luck.

Could you please suggest me on this?

Comment: This file name `Learning/Custom/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php` should be `Learning/Custom/Block/Adminhtml/Product/ProductEdit.php`

Comment: @Marius, it's a typing mistake. now see my thread is updated.

Comment: try putting in `$_template = 'Learning_Custom::catalog/product/edit.phtml'`

Comment: but standard way of overriding template files - [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-templates)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have the dependency defined ont the catalog module in your module.xml? This is important to ensure that your configuration overrides the catalog configuration:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/etc/module.xml#L11

You also might want to clean your var/generation folder. Depending on how the Product Block is instantiated this might also be an Issue

Comment: Yes previously I have declared (`sequence`) but not posted here now see I have updated my thread. And I have cleared as you instructed to clear `cache`, `var/generation`, `pub/static/adminhtml/Learning` and `var/view_preproccessed`, but no luck. If I comment my extending it's working other wise it's not working. Could you please suggest me on this?

Comment: so you replace the edit.phtml template?. You are missing some logic from here then: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit.phtml. specially the javascript to init the form

Comment: @DavidVerholen, I decided just copy the entire code from above link and past from my `edit.phtml` file and added my custom code, now working fine. Here I have a question? Is you are given link code is **Enterprise Edition** or **Community Edition**? why because I'm working on **EE**.

Comment: it's the community edition and actually from the develop branch so this is not stable code. The EE code should be the same since EE is, as far as I know, only added modules. But if you copy the code, you should copy it from the stable version(this is for 2.0.2): https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit.phtml

Comment: @DavidVerholen, Ok. When I copied the code from your given link the only the difference between those two files(**EE** and **CE**) are  `"Magento_Catalog/catalog/type-switcher"` and `"Magento_Catalog/catalog/type-events"`. and added last **javascript** `<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/product/weight-handler": {},
            "Magento_Catalog/catalog/apply-to-type-switcher": {}
        }
    }
</script>` what is means? is there any difference b/w?

Comment: there should not be a difference between CE and EE. The difference is that the first is from the develop (unstable) branch and the second is from the latest stable release

Comment: @DavidVerholen, ThankQ dude.